# Create Indicator to compare condition across any select columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I am looking to compare specific variables, where if any column is a specific value over a certain threshold, I can create a new indicator variable.

```
# example data
have <- tibble(id = c(1,2,3), one = c(0, 0, 1), two = c(0, 1, 1), three = c(0, 1, 1))
> have
# A tibble: 3 x 4
     id   one   two three
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
     1     0     0     0
     2     0     1     1
     3     1     1     1
```

In this case, my condition would be:

```
pseudocode: 
want <- have %>% 
    # if across these vars, any has this condition, return T/F
    # and then sum T/F, and use that sum to create indicator
    mutate(condition = across(one:three), 
        ~ ifelse(.x > 0, 1, 0) %>% 
          sum %>% ifelse(. > 2, 1, 0))
```

With the result being:

```
> want
# A tibble: 3 x 5
     id   one   two three condition
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
1     1     0     0     0         0
2     2     0     1     1         1
3     3     1     1     1         1
```

I'm not entirely sure if I'm using the `across` scoping correctly, because it looks like they're only used to apply functions to all columns, but any correction or help is appreciated.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if below is what you wan but you can have a look at it

```
want <- have %>% 
mutate(condition= ifelse(rowSums(select(.,one:three)) > 0, 1, 0))
```

output:

```
    id   one   two three condition
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
     1     0     0     0         0
     2     0     1     1         1
     3     1     1     1         1
```

Comment: Thank you, I ended up using a similar solution just adding combinations of conditions: `mutate(condition = case_when(one + two > 1 ~ 1, two + three > 1 ~ 1, one + three > 1 ~ 1,  TRUE ~ 0))`